# Windows UI Automation

Tags: c#, user-interface, automation

I was testing the follow sample code and somehow whenever I tried running it, I will have an error shown below. However, the calc.exe process was executed successfull, so how is it possible that the handle be null or zero? I hope you understand what I am trying to put across. Thanks! The code sample is from http://www.mathpirate.net/log/tag/system-windows-automation/

> An unhandled exception of type
>   'System.ArgumentException' occurred in
>   UIAutomationClient.dll
>   Additional information: hwnd cannot be IntPtr.Zero or null.

```
//Launches the Windows Calculator and gets the Main Window's Handle.
Process calculatorProcess = Process.Start("calc.exe");
calculatorProcess.WaitForInputIdle();
IntPtr calculatorWindowHandle = calculatorProcess.MainWindowHandle;

//Here I use a window handle to get an AutomationElement for a specific window.
AutomationElement calculatorElement = AutomationElement.FromHandle(calculatorWindowHandle);

if(calculatorElement == null)
{
    throw new Exception("Uh-oh, couldn't find the calculator...");
}

//Walks some of the more interesting properties on the AutomationElement.
Console.WriteLine("--------Element");
Console.WriteLine("AutomationId: {0}", calculatorElement.Current.AutomationId);
Console.WriteLine("Name: {0}", calculatorElement.Current.Name);
Console.WriteLine("ClassName: {0}", calculatorElement.Current.ClassName);
Console.WriteLine("ControlType: {0}", calculatorElement.Current.ControlType.ProgrammaticName);
Console.WriteLine("IsEnabled: {0}", calculatorElement.Current.IsEnabled);
Console.WriteLine("IsOffscreen: {0}", calculatorElement.Current.IsOffscreen);
Console.WriteLine("ProcessId: {0}", calculatorElement.Current.ProcessId);

//Commented out because it requires another library reference. However, it's useful to see that this exists.
//Console.WriteLine("BoundingRectangle: {0}", calculatorElement.Current.BoundingRectangle);

Console.WriteLine("Supported Patterns:");
foreach (AutomationPattern supportedPattern in calculatorElement.GetSupportedPatterns())
{
    Console.WriteLine("\t{0}", supportedPattern.ProgrammaticName);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You're misunderstanding [WaitForInputIdle](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20100325-00/?p=14493) (Which is a HORRENDOUSLY bad name for what that function currently does). You're asking for the address of the main window before a main window has even been created. As a result you end up passing an invalid window handle to your other functions.

EDIT: I would strongly recommend use of a UI Automation library such as [`white`](http://white.codeplex.com/) if you're going to be doing serious work with it.

Comment: If you're using White, be aware that it has a few issues; I found those quite significant on my current project.  You can see the list of White issues at: http://white.codeplex.com/workitem/list/basic

Comment: Btw, is this a recommended idea to use UI Automation for monitoring purposes?

I have a 3rd party application in which the values I want to monitor and based on the values, I would like to perform some actions, i.e. UI actions, clicking a button, changing textfield values etc.

As for monitoring values, do I have to individual monitor each control?

Thanks!